# Computer hangs when trying to start Software Center

Tags: software-center

Every time  I want to open **Software Center** to install something, my computer hangs before it starts. What could be the problem?

### AND

When I try `sudo apt-get update` and type my password, in the end of that I get error:

```
W: GPG error: http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F24AEA9FB05498B7
```

### EDIT

When I run `software-center` command from terminal, it does not give any errors, only thing it writes in output is:

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
2012-12-23 15:55:18,554 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2012-12-23 15:55:19,000 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
```

and after that it stays that way...

Answer (score 0):

there is a all time default solution which I am following if I saw any thing like that .

open your terminal 
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

paste the above line . 
try again .

Comment: ok, now trying ..

Comment: sorry, but problem still be continuing..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have installed steam without importing the key. Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F24AEA9FB05498B7
sudo apt-get update
```

It will import the key for the steam repository. Now you can open the Software Center again.

Comment: hm.. no, it imported key, but still can't open software center :(
p.s. now sudo apt-get update haven't gived any errors

Comment: Does Software Center give any errors when you run it by typing 'software-center' in a terminal?

Comment: I made edit, could you look at that please.

Comment: Hmm... try 'sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center'

Comment: i reinstalled it, and now when i run it from terminal, computer still works, but nothing changes. it writes output in edit, and stays that way. :(

Comment: Did you try to reboot your computer? If the problem persists, maybe you should report a bug by running 'ubuntu-bug software-center'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6834/discussion-between-zilvador-and-geoh)